# Не удается собрать APK в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

> C:\Users\YandexDisk\android--apps\2.7.0\extras\keystore\webviewapp.properties
> (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

Получаю следующую ошибку. Файл указанный в сообщение находится по этому же пути.

Comment: YandexDisk это название юзера?

Comment: @Super3283u нет. Название пользователя убрано из вопроса. В ошибке он есть.

Comment: На каком этапе ошибка?

Comment: @ArtyMorris Нажимаю Finish и через несколько секунд ошибка 0:00 Executing tasks: [:mobile:assembleRelease] in project     /     0:00 Gradle build failed in 2 s 246 ms      /     0:00 Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.